# How can I use print statements to debug? Output is not showing up in terminal log

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, vagrant

I cannot see a log of my print statements output in the terminal. What is missing? Print 1 and Print 2.

application.py code I am testing:

```
'''
# JSON APIs to view Category Information
@app.route('/catalog/json')
def categoriesJSON():
    categories = session.query(Category).all()
    categoryList = []
    for category in categories:
        categoryItems = session.query(CatalogItem).filter_by(
                            category_id=category.id).all()
        categoryItemsList = []
        for items in categoryItems:
            categoryItemsList.append(items.serialize)
        category = category.serialize
        category['items'] = categoryItemsList
        categoryList.append(category)
    print 1
    return jsonify(categories=categoryList)



# Show all categories
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/catalog/', methods=['GET'])
def showCategories():
    categories = session.query(Category).order_by(asc(Category.name))
    latest = session.query(CatalogItem).order_by(
                CatalogItem.id.desc()).limit(9)
    print 2
    return render_template('categoryIndex.html', categories=categories,
                           latest=latest, username=checkUserLogged())
'''
```

Terminal:

```
 * Detected change in '/Volumes/Sammy/UDACITY/BACKEND/fullstack/vagrant/catalog/application.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 129-965-757
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2018 18:04:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2018 18:04:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Detected change in '/Volumes/Sammy/UDACITY/BACKEND/fullstack/vagrant/catalog/application.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 129-965-757
 * Detected change in '/Volumes/Sammy/UDACITY/BACKEND/fullstack/vagrant/catalog/application.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 129-965-757
 * Detected change in '/Volumes/Sammy/UDACITY/BACKEND/fullstack/vagrant/catalog/application.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 129-965-757
```

The Chrome dev console error shows as:

> "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

Does that mean I need to download a jQuery library?

If I am routing `/catalog/json` which folder should I be running this application in the terminal? My path is `vagrant/catalog/json`. Do I need to be in the `vagrant` folder? I am currently in the `catalog` folder in my terminal.

Comment: Put in a string, this code will do nothing.

Comment: @Klaus D. Could you please clarify?

Comment: You put `'''` around the code which makes it a multi line string literal. Code in these string blocks is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the Bootstrap question:

You don't specifically need to *download* a jQuery library, you can simply reference it somewhere. But yes, Bootstrap requires jQuery to run.